# How to display one row from one table, and multiple rows from another table with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to display 1 table row, then underneath display multiple image urls (amount of images could be anywhere from 1 to 20) from another table using PHP and mySQL.

I'm using a join statement in the SQL so I can get mycode column, which is common to both tables. Then using two while loops display the data.

```
$sql = "SELECT   possessions.id,possessions.description,images.url,possessions.mycode,possessions.category
FROM possessions
RIGHT JOIN images ON possessions.mycode=images.mycode
ORDER BY possessions.id";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $mycode = $row[3];
    $sql2 = "SELECT images.url FROM images WHERE images.mycode=$mycode";
    echo "</br></br>";
    echo "description = " . $row[1];
    echo "</br></br>";
    if ($result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2)) {
      while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result2)) {
        echo $rows[0];
      }
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see this results in description being shown twice, and with this example two urls underneath, I just want to show the description once with both urls underneath.

```
description = Torch 18650

../upload/1563614178.jpg../upload/1563617891.jpg

description = Torch 18650

../upload/1563614178.jpg../upload/1563617891.jpg
```

I know the reason for this is the join in the sql statement, but I need to run this so I can get the mycode column from the images table to use in the second sql query.

SQL query output.

```
1   description url mycode  category    
6   Torch 18650     ../upload/1563614178.jpg    522     Electronics
6   Torch 18650     ../upload/1563617891.jpg    522     Electronics
```

Comment: . . Learn to use parameters when making calls to the database.  Don't munge query strings with literal values.

Comment: You want to display a row from a table. So select it. You want to show rows from another table. So select them. Why are you trying to put these two different things into one query?